# Why can't I test email sending in Rails 5?

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I'm trying to test email sending in a simple Rails 5 app using [cucumber](http://cucumber.io) and using the [ActionMailer guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-testing) and [Testing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers) with the following simple case. Can you help me see why it's not working?

app/mailers/test_mailer.rb

```
class TestMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: "to@example.org", subject: 'welcome!'
  end
end
```

features/test.feature

```
Feature: test email

  Background:
    Given we say "hello"

  Scenario: send mail
    Given 0 email is in the queue
     Then send an email
    Given 1 email is in the queue
```

features/steps/test_steps.rb

```
Given "we say {string}"  do |say_it|
  puts say_it
end

Given "{int} email is in the queue"  do |mail_count|
  puts "method    : #{ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method}"
  puts "deliveries: #{ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries}"
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count.should eq mail_count
end

Then "send an email"  do
  TestMailer.welcome_email.deliver_later
end
```

It keeps responding that there are no items in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my response to @diabolist, I had to modify my cucumber testing setup to support `:async` instead of `:inline`. This entailed:

config/environments/test.rb

```
...
config.active_job.queue.adapter = :test
...
```

features/support/env.rb

```
...
World( ActiveJob::TestHelper )
Around() do |scenario, block|
  perform_enqueued_jobs do
    block.call
  end
end
```

I realise I probably could have just switched my test adapter to `:inline`, but this will let me do some queue testing later — particularly with the `performed` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Don't deliver_later, deliver right now. If you deliver_later you have to run your background jobs before your mail will be added to the queue

Comment: Thank you. you put me on the right track. I missed the fact that 4.2->5.x switched the default queue adapter to :async from :inline and I had to properly support that. This can't be the answer because I'm definitely not changing the desired functionality to support testing, but it helped me see what the problem was - thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, I wasn't suggesting you change production functionality, was  suggesting you make your tests send the mail right away somehow. Sorry for not making that clearer. Anyhow glad I could help :)

Comment: Ahhh! Ok. Thanks for the clarification.